# Finding conditioned consecutive values in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple rows and columns filled with types and values. All are strings. I want to write a function that conditions:
1) which type I search (column 1)
2) a first value (column 2)
3) a second, consecutive value (in the next row of column 2)

I manage to write a function that searches one value of one type as below, but how do I add the second type? I think it might be with help of `df.shift(axis=0)`, but I do not know how to combine that command with a conditional search.

````
import pandas as pd

d = {'type': ['wordclass', 'wordclass', 'wordclass', 'wordclass', 'wordclass', 'wordclass',
 'english', 'english', 'english', 'english', 'english', 'english'],
 'values': ['dem', 'noun', 'cop', 'det', 'dem', 'noun', 'this', 'tree', 'is', 'a', 'good', 'tree']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

tiername = 'wordclass'
v1 = 'dem'
v2 = 'noun'

def search_single_tier(tiername, v1):
    searchoutput = df[df['type'].str.contains(tiername) & df['values'].str.match(v1)]
    return searchoutput

x = search_single_tier(tiername, v1)
print(x)```
````

Comment: To make it clearer, you want function that receives three arguments: x, y, z and returns a row where x is value for column1, y is values for column2 and z is the value of the next row which have x in column1?

Comment: Yes, that's want I want.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a function for doing this. Instead, try this:

```
In [422]: tiername = 'wordclass'                                                                                                                                                                            

## This equates `type` columns to `tiername`. 
## `.iloc[0:2]` gets the first 2 rows for the matched condition

In [423]: df[df.type.eq(tiername)].iloc[0:2]                                                                                                                                                                
Out[423]: 
        type values
0  wordclass    dem
1  wordclass   noun
```

### After Op's comment:

```
Find all consecutive rows like this:
tiername = 'wordclass'
v1 = 'dem'

In [455]: ix_list = df[df.type.eq(tiername) & df['values'].eq(v1)].index.tolist()

In [464]: pd.concat([df.iloc[ix_list[0]: ix_list[0]+2], df.iloc[ix_list[1]: ix_list[1]+2]])                                                                                                                 
Out[464]: 
        type values
0  wordclass    dem
1  wordclass   noun
4  wordclass    dem
5  wordclass   noun
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but I want to be able to change the values that I am looking for, and it doesn't give me all consecutive values dem and noun (there are two such combinations in the mwe).

Comment: @Eline Please check 2nd part of my answer. Updated.

Comment: If I understand this update correctly I cannot alter the second value, though, it just gives me the value following v1. I want to be able to find out if my v1 can be followed by a v2 that I set myself, say, if 'dem' can be followed by 'cop' or 'det' as well in my database.

Comment: What my update basically is, for a particular `tiername` and `v1`, return next row value which has the same `tiername` and `v1`. I thought this was the question. Now, you have made me confused.

Comment: To put it in normal language: I am interested in which combinations of words and wordclasses are found (and not found) in my database. For example: can the word 'this' follow the word 'tree'? Can a wordclass 'det' precede a wordclass 'noun'? I am also interested in the frequencies. To use Roim's words under the original post: I want a function that receives three arguments: x, y, z and returns all rows where x is the value for column1, y is the value for column2 and z is the value of the next row (which also has x in column1).